# can't delete the preview button

Tags: forms, 6

I have used the following code to delete the preview button which is on one of my create content type pages, but its not doing anything, what am I doing wrong?

```
function example_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
// Check for a particular content type's node form.
if ($form_id == 'example_content_type_node_form') {
drupal_set_message("entering formId");

unset ($form['preview']);
}
}
```

the drupal_set_message does go off, so I know that I am entering the if statement. I have put this code in a custom module (example_module).

Comment: Which version of drupal are you using?

Comment: drupal 6, so @Patrick Kenny's suggestion wont work

Comment: try using [a module instead](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29328/1730)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the code your self, there are already modules out there for exactly that!

**1. [Jammer Module](http://drupal.org/project/jammer)** (*Recommended*)

> > Hide or remove items from displaying including the **node and comment preview buttons**, node delete button, revision log textarea, workflow form on the workflow tab, and feed icon

**2. [Preview module](http://drupal.org/project/preview)** (*Less Recommended*)

- This module hasn't officially been released yet on Drupal 6 or 7, and it hasn't been updated in quite a while, so you may not want to use it on your live site

---

***However if your using drupal 7, it's already a built in feature:***

> For Jamming the Preview button for content types in Drupal 7, the functionality is built into core. Visit admin/build/node-type/blog (example for blogs), or by navigation path, Administer - Site building - Content types - edit - Submission form settings fieldset

---

**Edit:**  Since your using drupal 6, my recommendation is just to go with the [Jammer Module](http://drupal.org/project/jammer).

Comment: If you want to use a module, use the Jammer module.  (http://drupal.org/project/jammer)  The Preview module linked above has not had an official release for D6 or D7 and no work has been done on it for more than two years.

Comment: @PatrickKenny - Good point, I updated my answer.

Comment: I just installed Jammer and I set the option to delete the preview button, but it didn't work!

Comment: could you take a screenshot of what exactly you did?

Comment: You need to clear the cache (http://drupal.org/node/152983) any time you make a change to the Jammer module's settings.

Comment: I cleared the cache but nothing changed. I also tried to use jammer to delete the submit button, but that didn't work either. I created a screenshot but I'm not sure how to upload it here...

Comment: @user1015214 - one easy way to do it is to edit your question, and click add a picture, browse to the screen shot, and click upload, then copy the link that was added at the bottom, and past it here as a comment (btw, when u do this **do NOT save the edit**)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5uhU5.png

Comment: I still can't get the jammer module to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use custom code to delete the preview button.  On the Content Type administration page at admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type, you can selection `Disabled` for `Preview before submitting` under `Submission form settings`.  This will remove the preview button for that content type.

Comment: I'm using drupal 6 and I dont seem to have that url. Is that a drupal 7 url? How do you do this in drupal 6?

Comment: Yes, my solution is for Drupal 7.  On D6, I would use the Jammer module. (http://drupal.org/project/jammer)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do it programmatically; here's the code solution in case anybody else needs to do it this way.

**Disables comment preview for ALL node types**

```
/**
 * Disables comment preview button for ALL node types.
 */
function my_module_update_7001() {
  $node_types = array_keys(node_type_get_types());
  foreach ($node_types as $node_type) {
    variable_set('comment_preview_' . $node_type, DRUPAL_DISABLED);
  }
}
```

If you want to remove the subject/title field from all node types (as I did) add this line below the other `variable_set...`

```
variable_set('comment_subject_field_' . $node_type, DRUPAL_DISABLED);
```